# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with Angular

Tags: swagger, nswag, angular13, asp.net-core-6.0

I have the following setup: ASP.NET Core 6 Web API with controllers and an Angular 13 frontend.

Some of my controllers will be used by external parties to integrate into my system, while other controllers is specifically for the angular UI. I would like to use NSwag to generate the typescript client for the Angular specific controllers, while I have a separate Swagger json url / specification I can use to give to external parties, that do not show the angular controllers.

IE I need two sets / urls of swagger in the same API project. Can anyone perhaps help on how to configure swagger for this configuration?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

So, i had to do the same. I downloaded packages for WebApi project with angular:

- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen
- Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

  if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

And now access to swagger is from main applicationUrl/swagger, SPA proxy is normally working and redirecting to angular.